# Loop within For Loop -- PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, do-while

I'm trying to achieve a list of a random set of symbols listed out.  This seems like a simple task but......

Here is my code so far...

```
$symbol_array = array('&sect;', '$', '#', '@', '&hearts;', '?', '&#9733;', '&triangle;', '&smile;', '!', '&#8710;', '&#8224;', '&infin;', '&#9793;', '&#9739;', '&spades;', '&clubs;', '&#9834;', '&#9835;', '&#9788;', '&#1769;');

        $num1 = mt_rand(4, 10);

        $ans = pow($num1, 3);

        $symbols_selected_array = array();
        for($x = 0; $x < $num1; $x++){
            do{
                $symbol = $symbol_array[array_rand($symbol_array)];
            } while(in_array($symbol, $symbols_selected_array));
            $symbols_selected_array[] = $symbol;
            $symbols .= $symbols_selected_array[$x] . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        }
print_r($symbols_selected_array);
echo '<br><br>' . count($symbols_selected_array);
echo '<br><br>' . strlen($symbols);
echo '<br><br>' . $symbols;
```

The setting of `$num1` determines how many symbols will be shown (4 - 10).  The problem is that on rare occasion, there will be a list that is longer than 10.  I have no idea how/why this is happening or how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say it's longer than 10, does your count() still show 10 or 11?

Comment: `count` shows the proper amount, but it's just `$symbols` that sometimes ends up being longer than `count ()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems a little complicated. It seems like you just don't want the symbols repeated.

```
$symbol_array = array('&sect;', '$', '#', '@', '&hearts;', '?', '&#9733;', '&triangle;', '&smile;', '!', '&#8710;', '&#8224;', '&infin;', '&#9793;', '&#9739;', '&spades;', '&clubs;', '&#9834;', '&#9835;', '&#9788;', '&#1769;');

$num1 = mt_rand(4, 10);

$ans = pow($num1, 3); // You never use this?

shuffle($symbol_array);
$symbols_selected_array = array_slice($symbol_array, 0, $num1);
$symbols = implode('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $symbols_selected_array);

print_r($symbols_selected_array);
echo '<br><br>' . count($symbols_selected_array);
echo '<br><br>' . strlen($symbols);
echo '<br><br>' . $symbols;
```

Comment: Hey!  That's a better way to do it.  Thanks!  I still can't figure out why the issue was happening with my code, but this is definitely better.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure that `count($symbols_selected_array) > 10` happens? I just tried running your code in a loop one million times, checking for a list larger than 10.

```
$symbol_array = array('&sect;', '$', '#', '@', '&hearts;', '?', '&#9733;', '&triangle;', '&smile;', '!', '&#8710;', '&#8224;', '&infin;', '&#9793;', '&#9739;', '&spades;', '&clubs;', '&#9834;', '&#9835;', '&#9788;', '&#1769;');             

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {                                    
   $num1 = mt_rand(4, 10);                                           

   $symbols_selected_array = array();                                
   for($x = 0; $x < $num1; $x++){                                    
      do{                                                            
     $symbol = $symbol_array[array_rand($symbol_array)];             
      } while(in_array($symbol, $symbols_selected_array));           
      $symbols_selected_array[] = $symbol;                           
      $symbols .= $symbols_selected_array[$x] . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
   }                                                                 

   if (count($symbols_selected_array) > 10) {                        
      print "$num1<br/>\n";                                               
      print_r($symbols_selected_array);                              
      echo count($symbols_selected_array);                           
      echo "<br/><br/>\n";                                                   
      echo strlen($symbols);                                         
      echo "<br/><br/>\n";                                                   
      echo $symbols;                                                 
      echo "<br/><br/>\n";                                                   

      exit;                                                          
   }                                                                 
}
```

Can you really reproduce this?